# Can you prohibit updates to _design docs using validate_doc_update functions?

Tags: couchdb

I wanted to write a `validate_doc_update` function that looks like this:

```
function(newDoc, oldDoc, userCtx) {
    var db = userCtx.db;
    var docId = newDoc._id;
    if (db === '<dbName>' && docId.indexOf('_design') >= 0) {
        throw ({ forbidden: 'Design docs should be edited in the template DB '});
    };
};
```

Because I replicate from a template DB to a content DB. This allows me to reset while developing more easily (i.e. just delete from the content DB). I, and people I work with, often forget about _design docs in the content DB before we delete it. I would like to disallow views from being created in the content DB.

But the above doesn't prevent admins from creating or editing _design docs. I guess this makes sense, as you could lock yourself out of a DB quite easily..

How can I achieve this?

Comment: From my experience, the validate_doc_update doesn't seems to be called on the design documents. This  makes sense since we could loose access to the whole database by making an error in the doc update function. One thing you could do is to add some sort of reverse proxy validation. You could filter POST or PUT request for design documents.

Comment: I won't re-edit your question, since perhaps you did it intentionally, but it's considered bad practice to put tags in your title. Your question is already tagged 'couchdb', so titling the question with "CouchDB: " adds only noise.

Comment: Noted @Flimzy. I have done this for many posts. would it be worthwhile to change them all slowly?

Comment: @ZachSmith: No need to go on an editing rampage, but as you notice them, cleaning them up is good :)